# Facebook requestNewPublishPermissions Android not working

Tags: android, facebook, sdk, permissions, publish

So I'm trying to publish to facebook with my android app. I logged in with user, got a session, and try to request new permission "publish_actions", but the callback session doesn't include permission.

Pertinent code:

```
    if (!isSubsetOf(PERMISSIONS, permissions)) {
                    pendingPublishReauthorization = true;
                    Session.NewPermissionsRequest newPermissionsRequest = new     Session.NewPermissionsRequest(
                                this, PERMISSIONS);
                    session.requestNewPublishPermissions(newPermissionsRequest);
                    return;
                }

    private static final List<String> PERMISSIONS = Arrays
            .asList("publish_actions");

    private Session.StatusCallback sessionCallback = new Session.StatusCallback() {
        @Override
        public void call(final Session session, final SessionState state,
                final Exception exception) {
            if (state.isOpened() && isFbShareEnabled) {
                showPreview();
            }
        }
    };

uiHelper = new UiLifecycleHelper(getActivity(), sessionCallback);
        uiHelper.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
```

...and of course uiHelper is also calls onResume, onPause, onStop, onActivityResult, onSaveInstanceState & onDestroy, in those overriden functions.

The session never gets the publish_actions permission.
One final note: this works on most phones, but is not working on Galaxy Note 3, and Galaxy s4.

Thanks and appreciation beforehand!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

...and then, randomly, it was working today (at least on the note3, person with s4 is out of office today, so couldn't test)